# How disabled esLint "error Parsing error: Missing semicolon." for Heroku Procfile?

Tags: node.js, typescript, heroku, eslint, procfile

I'm trying to commit a Procfile worker for a Twitter bot to Heroku, which is located at "src/Procfile" with two other files "src/bot.ts" and "src/config.ts"

```
worker: node bot.ts
```

When commited esLint error:

```
 $ eslint --ext .js,.json,.ts --fix /Users/user-file/Codes/folder/twitter-bot/node-ts-starter/src/Procfile

/Users/user-file/Codes/folder/twitter-bot/node-ts-starter/src/Procfile
  2:13  error  Parsing error: Missing semicolon.

  1 | // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/semi
> 2 | worker: node bot.ts
    |             ^
  3 | 

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)
```

I tried commenting it out with:

```
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/semi
worker: node bot.ts
```

It didn't work.

last I tried putting the "Procfile" outside of the "src folder"

and edit the "Procfile" to:

```
worker: node src/bot.ts
```

it went thru but, it wasn't detected as a worker but a web page instead.

Appreciate the help, thanks in advance!

Comment: Never faced such types of issues . Are u sure its in root folder and everything is correct share errror too.

Comment: Hi thank you for your comment. My root-dir is the "src" folder, where I place the bot.ts, config.ts, and the Procfile.